# Merge function generates duplicates

Tags: r, database, merge, duplicates

This question is just to understand why this would happen.

I'm merging two databases:

```
bot.rep.geo <- merge(x = bot.rep, y = geo.2016, by = "cod.geo", all.x = TRUE)
```

The original databases have the following dimensions: `bot.rep` has 1634451 observations, `geo.2016` has 1393.

After merging using `all.x = TRUE`, the new database emerges with 1727681, instead of the same size as `bot.rep`.

Why does this happen?

After a quick review, I realised it was creating some duplicates, but I don't understand the reason and if I'm doing something wrong while using the `merge` function.

Comment: By choosing `all.x = TRUE` you are doing the equivalent of a `LEFT JOIN` in SQL.  This does not mean that a given row from `bot.rep` will appear only once.  Instead, it will appear once for each match in `cod.geo`, and each row in `bot.rep` is guaranteed to appear even if does not match to anything.

Comment: Show us some sample data and this will be clear.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen for the clarification. Is there any way to prevent this or just need to remove duplicates afterwards?

Comment: @RafaelSierra do a `unique(merge(x = bot.rep, y = geo.2016, by = "cod.geo", all.x = TRUE))`... it's the same as doing it afterwards... merge function doesn't have a unique parameter

Comment: You guys are right. I hadn't realised I had and issue with a particular variable that I was creating as a concatenate from 3 others. The variable was 1 1 11, but there is a case were a 1 11 1 can happen and I hadn't noticed it before. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be lines in the geo.2016 table where the cod.geo value appears twice or more.

if you have a bot.rep value of "X" in your bot.rep data, then 2 lines which contain "X" in the geo.2016 data, the merge will duplicate the line in bot.rep and join the 2 lines from geo.2016.

Comment: Thank you! I see now why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)), x has multiple rows matching in y.

See example below, where `bot.rep` `cod.geo` value of *1* has 2 matches in `geo.2016` dataset. Hence, we have 2 rows for 1 id. Also, notice we are creating `NA` rows for non matched ids because of `all.x = TRUE` argument.

Now, you need to decide which row is a duplicate for `cod.geo` value *1*.

```
#dummy data
bot.rep <- data.frame(cod.geo = 1:4)
geo.2016 <- data.frame(cod.geo = c(1,1,3,5,6), z = 1:5)

bot.rep.geo <- merge(x = bot.rep, y = geo.2016,
                     by = "cod.geo", all.x = TRUE)

#   cod.geo  z
# 1       1  1
# 2       1  2
# 3       2 NA
# 4       3  3
# 5       4 NA
```

You will find more info on different types of [merge functions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right?rq=1).

Comment: @akrun I don't think so, as it is asking the reason why this happens, not how to merge. If you feel it is a dupe feel free to vote to close, downvote, flag, etc.

Comment: I was just curious,